# CSS properties not appearing on text input

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to get some css properties to appear across my forms, but it's not working when I move the properties to the parent html element.
The CSS properties applied directly to the `.input` class work, but when applied to the parent `.form-control` class they don't work and don't seem to affect the input and none of the `.form-control` properties appear in Chrome dev tools if I inspect the text input element?

```css
.form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*.form-control .input {*/
/*height: 34px;*/
/*width: 100%;*/
/*margin: 10px;*/
/*border-radius: 4px;*/
/*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
/*}*/

.form-control .button {
  display: block;
  background-color: limegreen;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form className="form-control">
  <input className="input" type="text" />
  <button className="button">Get Weather</button>
</form>
```

Comment: why className="" and not class=""?

Comment: Very likely because OP is using React: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: Yes sorry I should have added I was using React.

Comment: I have updated your question to include the ReactJS tag as intended.

Comment: When you inspect the output html in your dev tools, do you see the attributes as "classname" or "class"?

Comment: Just as class (React transpiles, className to class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippet you provided, it's because you are applying the rules directly to the form and not the forms input. Input will not inherit the properties you are setting on the form. You need to specifically target the input like you have in the commented out code.